# IIS 7, loads blank screen

Tags: iis-7

I've just setup an application under the default web site installed by IIS 7.

I've tried loading both http://localhost and http://localhost/myappname

in both cases, all I am getting is a blank page, no errors. And although directory browsing is enabled, I can't even see a list of the files in that directory.

Any ideas why this is?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I followed what this guys suggested and it worked for me - http://obligious.blogspot.com/2011/12/iis-returns-blank-page.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it turned out that the Web Site was not loaded, because Skype was using port 80. However I needed a full system restart to get the web site to restart...

Answer (score 0):

IIS loads the default file when you try to access it that way. Check if you have a index.htm or default.aspx file. if not you will need to have a file with these names or you can set your the default file according in IIS under the document tab of properties.